Is there a rule for using demonstrative pronouns when referencing something in another sentence?
Considering this paragraph:

Those who find ugly meanings in beautiful things are corrupt without being charming. This is a fault.

And this one:

It is a sad thing to think of, but there is no doubt that genius lasts longer than beauty. That accounts for the fact that we all take such pains to over-educate ourselves.

What makes one use this or that in such cases?
This question is different from This/that way, or in this/that way? because that question is specifically about the usage of such pronouns followed by "way". My question is about the usage of demonstrative pronouns, in general, that reference in another sentence the subject of a previous sentence.

Both are fine in your context. It's just a meaningless stylistic choice. But if you're having problems making that choice, you could always fall back on Which is X / accounts for Y.

I've updated it.

this can express that you intend to talk further about it.  that can express that you want to abandon it to focus on something else.

The city is full of stray animals. This is a problem and we need to do something about it.  I suggest ...
The city is full of stray animals. That is a problem and we  need to do something about it. A more important problem, however, is the number of homeless people living on the streets, under bridges, under highway overpasses, in city parks, train stations, anywhere and everywhere there's a bit of shelter.


But this isn't a hard and fast rule. You can say "That is X. That is also Y."

That is why I did not present it as a "rule" and used the word "can".

I don't think That is the problem and this is my solution is any more or less natural than This is the problem and here is my solution. Maybe this + this and that + that don't work so well, but I don't think the choice of "demonstrative pronouns" matters much, providing the referents are contextually obvious.

@FumbleFingers Are you saying that what I've written is invalid ?  That this connotes topical nearness and 'that' connotes topical 'distance' is a bogus concept, and it comes down to "naturalness" and "obviousness"?

No, I'm saying that in contexts where both this and that are being referenced in the same sentence, you can't really apply the this = nearest principle. It's all the same whether you say This is the solution to this problem, This is the solution to that problem, That is the solution to this problem, or That is the solution to that problem. We know which is which because it's contextually obvious (one's a problem, the other's a solution). And who's to say which is metaphorically nearer or further? Mostly it's meaningless stylistic choice. That's (not "this is") all there is to it.

That's BS.  Why didn't I say "This is BS"?

Well, my question is about grammatical rules. There shouldn't be such debates. The answer should be yes, then say the rules, or no, there are no rules for such usage.
